# iPhone App Brush effects (Based on GLPaint)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GLPaint Brush Effect with blur and bevel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399852/glpaint-brush-effect-with-blur-and-bevel)

I am working on Drawing Application based on glpaint . I am creating different brush effects , now what i want is , to add Blur and Bevel to the particular brush. Can somebody give me a start ?

[image]

Above is my play Area and My brush is star shaped.