# GLPaint Brush Effect with blur and bevel

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, xcode4.2

I am working on a drawing application based on GLPaint code. Do somebody know how to get an effect like this  ? I have tried with different values for the width and the Height for the brush, but still it remains same .

Do i need to consider glBlendFunc() ? or Is it achievable thorough changing the width and the heigh of the brush.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Visit OpenGL reference.. There are so many functions. Play with them and you'll get that effect. It has nothing to do with brush size..

Comment: @anonymous do you know the exact parameter values for the above effect ? http://www.visualnewt.com/OpenGL/learning_iphones_opengl_es/part_iii_-_glpaint_dissecte.html  refer this , They have achieved the effect, But still wondering how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that type of effect is to reducing the alpha from 1.0 to 0.7.

Answer (score 1):

In PaintingView Change Brush `Height` and `Width` as shown in following image...And One more thing is that change brush image according to your requirements for more color custom effect..

[image]

Hope, this will help you..